# XSLT Remove Double or Single Quotes

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have a rudimentary understanding of how XSLT works and im confident that I need to use the Replace function in some way. but for the life of me I cant figure out how.

I am transforming an ugly Quickbooks xml report from the api into a CSV that I can manage and it does exactly what I want except there is an extra " in one of the Blocks that is throwing everything off the exported row and im not sure how to check for that in the XSLT file

Here is the xslt file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
<xsl:variable name="Quotes" select="'&quot;'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/GeneralDetailReportQueryRs/ReportRet/ReportData/DataRow">
<xsl:value-of select="$Quotes"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./RowData/@value[../@rowType]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=2]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=3]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=4]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=5]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=6]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=7]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=8]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=9]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=10]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=11]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=12]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$Quotes"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the specific line in questions is this:

```
                    <DataRow  rowNumber="1409">
                        <RowData  rowType="item" value="Triaxle Stone 2A Modified 3/4&quot;" />
                        <ColData  colID="2" value="Sales Order" />
                        <ColData  colID="3" value="2020-04-24" />
                        <ColData  colID="4" value="2020-04-24" />
                        <ColData  colID="5" value="5810" />
                        <ColData  colID="6" value="SCHMIDT, JOHN" />
                        <ColData  colID="7" value="22" />
                        <ColData  colID="8" value="21.65" />
                        <ColData  colID="9" value="0.35" />
                        <ColData  colID="10" value="ton" />
                        <ColData  colID="11" value="354.86" />
                        <ColData  colID="12" value="5.65" />
                    </DataRow>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? Your stylesheet says `version="1.0"`. Some (very few) XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT `str:replace{}` extension function. Without it you will need to use a recursive named template, as shown in the link.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you, im not sure I understand how to use a recursive named template? Do i include that in my template or do i call it into my template like a function? i know the the link shows how to use it in your template, but im not sure where to put the actual recursive named template

Comment: A named template is called using the `xsl:call-template` instruction, similar to a function. Templates cannot be nested; all templates must be at the top level of your stylesheet. If you cannot make it work, post a new question with your attempt - and make sure to include an example of the input too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your XML/XSLT combination with the XSLT-1.0 processor `xsltproc` on Linux. And it worked flawlessly. The only `"` (`&quot;`) in your XML indicated the measurements of an item (`3/4"`).

But if you'd really need to remove this `"` char, you could remove it from the output with the `fn:translate()` function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(./RowData/@value[../@rowType],'&quot;','')"/>
```

or, in some context

```
...
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="DataRow">
<xsl:value-of select="$Quotes"/>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(./RowData/@value[../@rowType],'&quot;','')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ColData/@value[../@colID=2]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Quotes,$delimiter,$Quotes)"/>
...
```

Comment: Ok, so if I was worried about double quotes, in the entire file i would need to change all the similar select statements to translate...(12 times in total) I found a copy of my report that was produced directly from quickbooks and they just have al the double quotes, doubled so that they do not affect the delimiter so it would look like this:  Triaxle Stone 2A Modified 3/4&quot;&quot; so i might end up using your translate statement to double them instead of remove them. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: if i wanted to change it from one double quote to 2 double quotes, how would i do that? the translate only lets me do a 1 for 1 exchange

Comment: Then you'd have to use the `replace` function (of XSLT-2.0 or above). The only XSLT-1.0 possibility to achieve this is by using a recursive approach with a named template, as mentioned in the comments above.